# How to level my front porch?

Tags: repair

My front porch, which is concrete, is leaning to one side. How can I fix it? I had a contractor look at it and he wanted to pour another porch on top of it, but I read somewhere that the preferred approach would be to jack it up somehow? Wondering what the best approach is and ballparks on expected cost would be great. I have a picture but I guess I need more reputation to post it :(

Comment: If you post a link to the picture, one of the higher rep users can edit it into the question.

Comment: what are the dimesions and how many steps to the ground?  A pic would be most helpful.

Comment: Picture here: can a higher rep user edit it into the question? https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B4JV18drrN2jU1FicVZ3TVdSWWFOOHJXb3BnS3FtZw

Comment: Here is another pic: can a higher rep user edit it into the question? https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B4JV18drrN2jdGZ6MnhHV19UM09jelRodGx3dTUyQQ

Comment: I guess it isn't technically a "porch", but rather a "landing" on the way to the porch. There are 2 steps leading up to the landing. The landing is 4'x4' (not including attached steps). The steps face south, and the entire concrete landing/steps structure is leaning east (away from the house). From the landing, you step up to the west to the actual "porch", which is _not_ leaning.

Answer (score 3):

The techniques used are all similar but seems to have regional names.It is called slab lifting,mudpumping,etc.The method is to pump a slurry under the pad and lift it.I would check for a foundation repair company that has good local references.I have no idea of cost.I'm sure it varies based on the size of the slab,amount of lift.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't just add concrete on top to level out. If you do so you don't take away the real issue and sooner or later you'll face the same problem.

New concrete on top would only help if it was never level. I bet it was level in the past, no? So that means it has been sinking to one side because of lack of foundations.

I don't know the exact terminology in English but you could dig underneath it alternating in blocks of 60cm. So it stays up on columns of 60cm. Then add more concrete (with iron). Then wait at least 30 days so the concrete can dry out. At that point dig out the other 60cm blocks and do the exact same thing.

That way you have the foundations improved and now you could add concrete on top to level out. But only after you fixed the real issue.

Comment: Pouring concrete on top would probably make it worse, anyway - since the part that was lower would then have thicker concrete on top, making it heavier, thus exacerbating what probably caused the problem to begin with.